# How to create a global configuration file?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a global configuration file in my php project, essentially, I have this content:

```
class SystemConfiguration 
{
   // Settings

   public static $base_url    = 'http://localhost/Application/';
   public static $db_host     = 'localhost';
   public static $db_name     = 'app';
   public static $db_username = 'root';
   public static $db_password = '123456';
}
```

now the content above is placed into `config.php` file, this file is in available in the `root/settings/` folder.
Now what I'm trying to achieve is get the variable included in the `SystemConfiguration` file from other file, what I tried, for example in the `index.php`:

```
 <?php
      require_once("system/config.php");

      $this->$base_url;
```

but when I load `index.php` I get fail to load response data in the network console tab, what I did wrong?

Comment: `SystemConfiguration::$base_url`

Comment: 1) You're not instantiating the class; 2) $this refers to the class itself, from _within_ the class; 3) Your properties are _static_ , by the way; 4) is the path right? 5) Why a class in the first place, and not a simple array?

Comment: how config.php available in root/settings/ and require_once("system/config.php");?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy root is just the folder where all files are available. Anyway, is possible insert in a variable all SystemConfiguration variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after including the folder has your class you can call its vars by doing an object from your class, in case static variables you can call directly like below:

```
SystemConfiguration::base_url;
```

where you can call static variables by :: and in case non static you call them by initialize object from your class:

```
$object_system_configuration = new SystemConfiguration();
$object_system_configuration->base_url;
```

Comment: If I call `$object_system_configuration->base_url;` isn't printed anything, why?

Comment: because your variable is static variable and static members accessible by class you don't need initialize an object, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: No @Sandokan if you read the answer accurately you will see I gave the example for more indication if you want use none static vars in your class you can use like this.